# Regex finding aa but not aaa with grep

Tags: r, regex

Can't figure out the regex pattern for matching aa but not aaa.

```
x <- c("ab", "abc", "abcc", "abccc", "abcccc", "abccccc")

grep(pattern="c{2,3}", x, value=TRUE, perl=TRUE)
## [1] "abcc"    "abccc"   "abcccc"  "abccccc"

grep(pattern="^((?!c{4,}).)*$", x, value=TRUE, perl=TRUE)
## [1] "ab"    "abc"   "abcc"  "abccc"
```

But what's the pattern to yield:

```
grep(pattern=..., x, value=TRUE, perl=TRUE)
## [1] "abcc"  "abccc"
```

Comment: Your title does not seem to match your question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> But what's the pattern to yield [1](https://ideone.com/yfuFaP) "abcc"  "abccc"

You need to assure that the 2 or 3 `c`s are not preceded nor followed with `c`:

```
grep(pattern="(^|[^c])c{2,3}([^c]|$)", x, value=TRUE)
```

**Details**:

- `(^|[^c])`  - an alternation group matching start of string (`^` anchor) or any char other than `c` (with a negated character class (bracket expression) `[^c]`)
- `c{2,3}` - 2 or 3 `c`s
- `([^c]|$)` -  an alternation group matching end of string (`$` anchor) or any char other than `c`

Alternatively, use a PCRE regex with lookarounds if your `c` is actually a placeholder for a multicharacter substring:

```
grep(pattern="(?<!c)c{2,3}(?!c)", x, value=TRUE, perl=TRUE)
```

See the [R demo](https://ideone.com/yfuFaP)

The `(?<!c)` negative lookbehind will fail the match if there is a `c` right before 2 or 3 `c`s and `(?!c)` negative lookahead fails the match if there is a `c` right after the 2 or 3 `c`s.

Comment: Thanks very much for the detailed answer and the explications!

Answer (score 2):

This should work for your test cases:

```
^[^c]+c{2,3}$
```